A movie from the 70s, 80s, or 90s like John Carter (2012) with a guy from Earth, a girl, and a caveman/tribesmen
When I was younger I watch this sci-fi/fantasy movie on YouTube but I can't remember its name. It had a man from Earth getting transported to another world. He meets a lady, who turns into his love interest, and a caveman. They travel through the desert. At the end, the villain sends the man back to Earth with some trick. I think there's a battle too. I think it's most likely a late 70s, '80s or '90s b-movie.

Have you tried searching your YouTube viewing history?

I don't think my youtube history would go back that far. Especially with the updates to youtube

If it was a comedy, it might have been "Cavegirl" (1985). A nerdy guy gets sent back in time. Meets a cavegirl (love interest) and her tribemates and chief. The tribemates constantly interfere with his romantic attempts, and the chief is constantly messing with and breaking his gear trying to figure out what it is.

I wonder if this is Gor (1987), based on John Norman's feminist(*) fantasy series? The early Gor novels, on which the movie was based, were very much Carter of Mars pastiches.
Most of the details you mention match: the transporting from Earth, meeting a love interest, desert, battle, tragically being sent back to Earth separating him from the lady-love (sniff!), are all there.
But I don't remember a caveman, although there was a scene in a cave with some tribesmen. Too, the way he gets sent back to Earth is different from what you recall.
It wasn't a B-film though, it was way lower than that. It's still on youtube, so you can check and see if it's what you remember.



(*) May not actually be feminist.

The movie you are describing sounds like "Yor, the Hunter from the Future" (1983). This film is a science fiction fantasy adventure, often considered a B-movie due to its production quality and campy elements.
Here's how it matches your description:

Man from Earth transported to another world: The protagonist, Yor, appears to be from Earth but is in a prehistoric, fantasy world.
Meets a lady who becomes his love interest: Yor meets and falls in love with a woman named Ka-Laa.
Meets a caveman: Yor encounters various primitive people, including a caveman named Pag.
Travel through the desert: Yor and his companions travel through different terrains, including deserts.
Villain sends the man back to Earth with some trick: There is a main antagonist, and while the specific detail of sending Yor back to Earth might be a bit off, the villain's schemes create a climactic struggle.
Battle: The movie features several battles, including Yor fighting against the villain's forces.


Where is this plot summary from?

Gor vs Yor! Who. Will. Win?
